# react pass data to two component,but one render failed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

I use react to make a submenulist.The parent component get json, pass the json to another two child component.But the only child success to display, another one failes.Two childs shared the grandson component.

```
class SubMenu extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var submenulink = require("../../../conf/navigation.json")

  return (
    <div>
       <PoliticsSubMenu politics_link={submenulink.politics}/>
       <LawSubMenu law_link={submenulink.law}/>
    </div>
)}}


class PoliticsSubMenu extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <SubMenuList link={this.props.politics_link} />
)}}

class LawSubMenu extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.law_link)
    return (
      <SubMenuList link={this.props.law_link}/>
    )
  }
}
class SubMenuList extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const links = this.props.link;
    const listNames = links.map((item) =>
      <li>{item.description}</li>
    )

    return (
      <li className="active">
          <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">politics</a>
          <ul className="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
              <li>{listNames}</li>
          </ul>
      </li>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hard coded your "submenulink" object around your example code and it's rendering in this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/pmx95r935m. What does your "navigation.json" file look like?

```
class SubMenu extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var submenulink = {
      politics: [{ description: "First" }, { description: "Second" }],
      law: [{ description: "Premiero" }, { description: "Segundo" }]
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <PoliticsSubMenu politics_link={submenulink.politics} />
        <LawSubMenu law_link={submenulink.law} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Other thoughts:

1. The SubMenuList component shouldn't have an `<li>` tag around `{listNames}`. Each listName item has an `<li>` around it.
2. The SubMenuList has a `listNames` list. Lists should contain keys. i.e.: `links.map((item, i) => <li key={i}>{item.description}</li>)` "Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give the elements a stable identity" from https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html.
3. A simple syntax for components without state (AKA: "dumb" components) can keep component definitions concise.

   ```
   const PoliticsSubMenu = (props) => <SubMenuList link={props.politics_link} />;
   ```

Comment: {"politics": [{
   "description": "GlobalPolitics",
   "link": "https://twitter.com/digitalocean"
  },
  {
   "description": "PoliticalParties",
   "link": "https://www.facebook.com/DigitalOceanCloudHosting"
  },
  {
   "description": "Organization",
   "link": "https://github.com/digitalocean"
  }
 ],"law": [{
   "description": "CivilLaw",
   "link": "https://twitter.com"
  },}

Comment: I updated the CodeSandbox example with your JSON string. I discovered a few problems. The semicolons and trailing commas should not be there. Also, the "law" array wasn't closed. Here is the JSON string corrected. `{ "politics": [ { "description": "GlobalPolitics", "link": "twitter.com/digitalocean" }, { "description": "PoliticalParties", "link": "facebook.com/DigitalOceanCloudHosting" }, { "description": "Organization", "link": "github.com/digitalocean" } ], "law": [ { "description": "CivilLaw", "link": "twitter.com" } ] }` Maybe this was your issue?

Comment: I think ours code is the same,but law in my code is disappear

Comment: I found , in the inspector, there are politics and law in the tag <li>,but it can not display in the browser

Comment: Hmm, I simplified the [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pmx95r935m) as best I could. (The PoliticsSubMenu and LawSubMenu components were identical so I cut them.) It's all working there. I'd suggest trying to duplicate the CodeSandbox example at this point. I'm not sure what else to suggest. Sorry. Do you have any more details?

Comment: I did just notice that your SubMenuList component was using a `div` to wrap SubMenuList `li` children. I adjusted that as well in the CodeSandbox.

Comment: May I have sent the project to you for  email?

Comment: I’d review it on GitHub. I’d like to keep the conversation public so users can follow it.